# Excel worksheet change event is not firing

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, worksheet-function, excel-automation

I have created excel workbook using .NET interop. The excel workbook is created successfully through my C# code. When the user makes any changes in the excel, I want to do some stuff. I have used the `ExcelWorkSheet.Change` event. But this event is not firing. Here is my code-

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;    
public class xxx  
{   

    static Excel.Application xlApp;  
    static Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;  
    static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;  
    static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
    static Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler EventDel_CellsChange;   
    public static void ExportToExcel()
    {           
        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue); 
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);  
        ---------------- data is dumped to the excel here----------------  
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkSheet).Activate();
        xlApp.EnableEvents = true;
        EventDel_CellsChange = new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(Worksheet_Change);  
        xlWorkSheet.Change += EventDel_CellsChange;
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\Test.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);  
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet1);
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);  

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.xlsx;");
        response.TransmitFile(("D:\\Test.xlsx");
        response.Flush();
        response.End();  
    }  

    public static void Worksheet_Change(Excel.Range Target)
    {
        try
        {
            xlApp.EnableEvents = false;                
            Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("Y2");                
            range.Formula = "=A2";                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        }
        finally 
        {
            xlApp.EnableEvents = true;
        }
    }  
}
```

No change is reflected in the Excel file when the user makes some changes.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Worksheet_Change event is not global - it only applies to that particular worksheet. In your code you wire up the event handler to the xlSheet1.Change event, then close the workbook and release all the Excel objects.

EDIT: I popped your code behind a Form and adapted it slightly. I could get the event to fire and the formula in cell Y2 is set. I'm not 100% sure of your circumstances, but try this code and then compare with your own. Hope it helps.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Excel.Application xlApp;

    private static Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

    private static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

    private static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;

    private static Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler EventDel_CellsChange;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
        //---------------- data is dumped to the excel here----------------  
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkSheet).Activate();
        xlApp.EnableEvents = true;
        EventDel_CellsChange = new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(Worksheet_Change);
        xlWorkSheet.Change += EventDel_CellsChange;   
    }

    public static void Worksheet_Change(Excel.Range Target)
    {
        try
        {
            xlApp.EnableEvents = false;
            Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("Y2");
            range.Formula = "=A2";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            xlApp.EnableEvents = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that the Worksheet Change event applies to a particular worksheet. In my code, I have wired it to `xlWorkSheet`. But still the event is not firing.

Comment: But isn't xlWorksheet in xlWorkbook, which you're immediately closing after you've wired up the event?

Comment: Yes. So where should I close the workbook and release the objects. Im breaking my head over this. Please help.

Comment: Try commenting out the lines between and including "xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);" and "releaseObject(xlApp);", then make a change on the worksheet and see if the change event fires as you would expect.

Where workbook closing and releasing should take place is probably an SO question all of its own.

Comment: I commented the lines you suggested. Still the same. Can't see anything happening in the Excel file :(

Comment: I put your code behind a WinForm button and could get the Change event to fire, and cell Y2's formula is set. I've updated my answer with the code I used. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this works fine in winform. But in my case, after the file is created I'm transmitting the file to user's machine using Response object. I guess this is causing the problem. I have edited my code to show how I'm doing this. Please help

Comment: If you're sending the code to another machine, the event will never fire, as the event exists on your server machine. Why not put VBA code into your template Excel file to achieve your aims?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i did exactly as u suggested and its working fine :)